# PHP/MySQL If FROM Statements

Tags: php, mysql

sorry for the extremely basic question!! I'm very new to PHP/MySQL

How would it be possible to do an if statement referencing wherever or not data was from a certain table.

Would this work?

```
if ( $search FROM "table2" ) 
{
function for table2.. etc
}
```

---

TABLE:**INSTRUMENTS**

COLUMNS:

```
 id   instrument    grade   standard    comments    
      instrument2   grade2  standard2   comments2   
      instrument3   grade3  standard3   comments3   
      instrument4   grade4  standard4   comments4   
      instrument5   grade5  standard5   comments5
```

TABLE: **PEOPLE**

COLUMNS:

```
id  first  last  snumber  course  email  graduate  inumber
```

Basically a person from the PEOPLE table is linked via ID to instruments in the INSTRUMENTS table, I have an e-mail search function that I need to send out the relative data to the relative instruments.

I want to get the comments[i] , grade[i], standard[i] of the matching instrument[i]

Comment: You´re mixing up PHP and MySQL, what exactly do you wanna achieve?

Comment: do you mean table in a database? If so, you should look up about [SQL](http://www.sql.org/) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)

Comment: How does the preceding query look like?

Comment: No, I wouldn't... What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Tobiask Woops! - I basically want to link some tables to some-other tables when I send out an e-mail

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean by "link", perhaps you can do this within your SQL statement

Comment: There is no such language as "PHP/MySQL". There is no "FROM" operator in PHP.

Comment: Are those table SQL table or you are talking about an array here? Could you be clearer?

Comment: Its a musicians database with instruments in tables eg, instrument1, instrument2, instrument3 etc - I also have grade1, grade2, grade3 and comments1, comments2, comments3 - I need to have this if statement so that it sends the correct additional data with the e-mail for the search function

Comment: Please **edit** your question to give the tables (and columns) used, and some ascii art of want you want the output to be.

Comment: @Johan done I think that is clear?

Comment: @Toby, much much better.

Comment: @Johan - I had an idea of stripping the last number from my colums and linking them, would that possibly work?

Comment: @Toby, not sure what you mean, please see the answer below I suggested some alterations to the layout of the tables, hope I got your intent correct.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you must already have specified the table to select from. You can use the same logic to see which table you initially used?

For example:

```
$sTable = 'table2';
$rResult = mysql_query(sprintf($sQuery, $sTable));
if ($sTable == 'table2') { // use $rResult }
```

Answer (score 1):

You know what table it came from, because *you* retrieved it from that table.

**Update**

Perhaps:

```
$search = trim(stripslashes($_POST['search']));
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

//Find instruments searched for:

$query = "
  SELECT *,
         ('$search' IN `instrument`)  AS `matched1`,
         ('$search' IN `instrument2`) AS `matched2`,
         ('$search' IN `instrument3`) AS `matched3`,
         ('$search' IN `instrument4`) AS `matched4`,
         ('$search' IN `instrument5`) AS `matched5`
   FROM `instruments`
  WHERE '$search' IN (`instrument`, `instrument2`, `instrument3`, `instrument4`, `instrument5`)
";
```

Explore the results and find out how to use them to your advantage.

This isn't the most glamourous solution and you can no doubt improve this with a different approach, but it's something to get you started.

Comment: Yes, I know that however I have an function which will generate an e-mail providing what data has been inserted. It is a musicians database with instruments in tables eg, instrument1, instrument2, instrument3 etc - I also have grade1, grade2, grade3 and comments1, comments2, comments3 - I need to have this if statement so that it sends the correct additional data with the e-mail for the search function

Comment: Those are tables, not columns? Your database design sounds broken to me.

Comment: Argh - sorry they are columns!

Comment: @Toby: I think we're going to need to see a proper testcase. The query you use, and how you pull the results from it.

Comment: @Toby: you **need** to look up security best practices for DB querying in PHP. Even if you don't have access to PDO, you should have mysqli.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the headsup, I'm a little bit confused about the secruity issues with MySQL injection etc.

Comment: @Toby: (someone will correct me if I'm wrong) the best was to stop worrying about SQL injection is to use [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), as they do all the escaping for you. You fill in the query with parameter place holders, and pass in the values for the parameters.

Comment: @Toby: [Add such details by editing your question.] Unfortunately, there's no clear way. You've thrown that information away in your catch-all query. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,

The tables need a redesign IMHO.

I would change table **instruments** to.

```
id, people_id, instrument, grade, standard, comments
```

This query:

```
SELECT 
  people.email
  ,instruments.instrument
  ,instruments.grade
  ,instruments.standard
  ,instruments.comment
FROM people
INNER JOIN instruments ON (instruments.people_id = people.id)
WHERE people.id = 10
```

Will give you all instruments for person number 10.
You can change the `where` clause to `where people.snumber = x` or whatever you feel like.
Or add extra clauses to limit the number of instruments by adding something like : `AND instrument.grade > 7` at the end

With this setup people can have any number of instruments.
It feels a bit odd to -reverse link- the instruments to people like this, but believe me... it works.

I recommend reading up on joins (google 'mysql join') and always use explicit joins using the `join` keyword, it makes understanding your queries much easier.

If this is the result you where looking for, then you can drop the `inumber` field from the `people` table, since we moved the link between people and instruments to the instrument table.

On an 1-to-many link the linking field should always be on the 'many'-table.

Comment: @Johan - I sort of understand what you mean, however my search function is done via a drop list of instruments (enum data) there is a function that scans the database for the instruments already in the instruments colum. So how would I search for people who play a certain instrument?                -Also how could I add more then one instrument, how would the ID link with the people_id?

Comment: To search for people playing instrument X: SELECT * from people inner join instrument on (instrument.people_id = people.id) where instrument.instrument = 'tuba'

Comment: To insert more than one instrument: select @id:= people.id from people where people.email = 'joe@example.com'; insert into instrument values (null, @id, 'tuba', 10, 1, null),(null,@id,'piano',8,1,null);

Comment: I'm totally confused now :S - Sorry I'm very new to all this. Is it possible I could send my code to you (both my adding to the db and searching the db pages) and you could have a look for me?

Comment: Finally to get the people_id after adding a new person. insert into people values (null, 'toby' 'last', 10, 10 , 'tlast@example.com', 1); select @people_id:= last_insert_id(); *note the ";" separating commands they allow you to do two or more commands in one go. the MySQL function `last_insert_id()` gets you the last inserted autoincrementing id. So your id **must** be a primary integer autoincrementing key for that to work.

Comment: Sure, if you ask a new question in as non-confused manner as possible :-)

Comment: @Johan Thank you so much for your  help so far, OKAY here goes.... My site code is here http://rapidshare.com/files/457095816/searchtest.zip - It starts with index.php which adds data to PEOPLE table and generates an unique ID and an inumber (which determs the number of instruments played) Then we go to verify1.php where via a loop and the number set in inumber we have data insertion for INSTRUMENTS table and the instruments. verify2.php adds this data to INSTRUMENTS table and adds unique ID linking instruments to people tables. - I then have searchtest.php which is my search function

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store what table the search result was from in a variable, and compare the two variables.

```
if($search === "table2")
```

There is no from operator in PHP.